# Item Templates in Microsoft Visual Studio for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've tried about seven times to create an item template following the exact instructions on the microsoft website but I have been able to get it to work. After I export my template, it doesn't show up when I try to create a new CPP or Header file. Why is this?

Here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtoGh.jpg) is a image gallery of my EXACT steps. My apologies if this is not the correct board for such a question, but the MVS support is frankly useless.

Edit: Not sure why adding the tags "visual studio" is forbidden for users with less than 1500 reputation. Maybe a mod can correctly tag it.

Comment: Added image gallery as it did not display the first time.

Comment: Did you try to create the item template with another name (different from the project it is derived from and any name that exists on your disk) and then to look for this name first under your own Visual Studio folder and on full disk ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, can you elaborate a bit more? I don't quite understand. Have you also been able to create templates in MVS?

Comment: I used them looong time ago (VS6 ...). I now use Express versions that cannot create templates but only use them. That's the reason why I posted a comment and not an answer ... The idea is to first ensure that VS actually created (exported) the template and where.